# Diffrence between _Id and Id in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

What's the difference between those two lines in JPA

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
    List<Post> findByUser_Id(Long id);
}
```

And

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
    List<Post> findByUserId(Long id);
}
```

So i edited my question to be more clearly and get a good response so there is my domain classes User and Post and i have relation **@ManyToOne** in Post class.

Domain

```
...
public class Post implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

...
```

And

```
...
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

...
```

Comment: Are they in the same package?  Do they come from different libraries? PostRepository appears to be a custom interface that extends the Spring JpaRepository so the difference is domain specific to the creator.  I suspect that these are different versions of the same interface.  The difference in method signature may have coincided with a change to how Posts were identified (e.g. was using the `id` property but now uses a `_id` property).  If these are, in fact, the same interface with revision then you may have a dependency problem if both are available.

Comment: yes, they are in the same package, no they come from the same libraries. and for domain class they are the same `private Long id;`. thanks for that but i think its not clearly like i suspect. but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring Data JPA then class is a [Spring JPA repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) in which the implementation is done by the Spring Framework and the method name is used for construction of the query.

Check [2.3.2 Query creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for how the query will be constructed.

So, in your case `List<Post> findByUser_Id(Long id);` method might throw error on runtime since it's not in valid method format.

Comment: thanks, my friend i think i have a good response but i cant say it's useful because my reputaion is under 15

Answer (score -1):

Its just the name of the method. Other than that, there is no difference between those lines.

Comment: Thanks for this response but i think we have other reason to do this in jpa.